# How to get children components in nextjs?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I need to build a hook to do some generic styles and use it around my project. I tried to do the following:

```
export const useTextStyles = () => {
  const styles = {
    TextMd,
  };

  return styles;
};

const TextMd: React.FC<{ className: string }> = ({ className }) => {
  return (
    <p
      className={`block transform transition-colors duration-200 py-2 hover:text-gray-800 text-gray-800 .leading-relaxed ${className}`}
    ></p>
  );
};
```

I use it around like this:

```
import { useTextStyles } from '../utils/stiles.tsx'
//...
const { TextMd } = useTextStyles();
//into html code:
<TextMd>Hello world</TextMd>
```

This doesn't work, probably because I have to pass the children explicitely.. Maybe I am doing it wrong.. In that case what is the best solution to do that in nextjs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the children property

```
import {ReactNode} from 'react' 

const TextMd: React.FC<{ className: string, children: ReactNode }> = ({ className, children }) => {
  return (
    <p
      className={`block transform transition-colors duration-200 py-2 hover:text-gray-800 text-gray-800 .leading-relaxed ${className}`}
    >{children}</p>
  );
};
```